# If $a(t) t$ is increasing for all $t>0$ then $(a(|x|)x- a(|y|)y)(x-y)>0, \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}^N,x\neq y $?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I foud in a paper this: from this conditions : The function $a(t)t$ is increasing in ($0,+\infty)$, that is,
$$(a(t)t)' > 0, ~\text{for all}~ t > 0$$

We have that $$(a(|x|)x- a(|y|)y)(x-y)>0, \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}^N,x\neq y $$

I don't know why ?

Thank you .

Comment: So I assume $a>0$?

Comment: in this paper there is not this hypothesis, but in other paper i found  this condition

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(t)=a(t)\,t$, so that $f$ is (strictly) increasing. Then if $x\ne y$
$$
(f(x)-f(y))\,(x-y)>0,
$$
since both factors on the left hand side have the same sign.

**Edit**: this does not answer the question, in which $a$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$.